# JBoss Custom Login Module Only Works Once

Tags: java, jboss

I have written a custom login module for JBoss that authenticates/authorizes requests to a web service. The first call to the service authenticates fine. I can connect a debugger to the login module and trace the code execution. However, all subsequent calls to the  web service skip the login module entirely. It appears JBoss/jaas is reusing the results of the first connection.

I'm stuck. Any suggestions to get me over the hump?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was trying to setup cookie based authentication. Apparently, JBoss/Jaas caches successful authentications based on username and password and cookies are ignored. To get things working, I dropped the cookie from the web service request and replaced it with a username and password in the authentication header.

Answer (score 0):

Is the authentication/authorization associated with a session object?  How have you set the timeout/invalidation of the session?

JBOSS is probably caching the credential somehow.  You *want* it to skip the login module in that case.  You should only invalidate it if you log out or timeout the session.

Did you test it with two separate users/browsers, each with their own session?

Comment: I have the same thought, JBoss is caching something. Since this is a custom security module for a stateless web service, I would prefer to cache the credentials myself. I would like to disable the JBoss caching and have the login module execute every time.